# Laravel : Query Builder - Using Clause WHERE NOT IN + AND WHERE another table statement throw error

Tags: database, laravel

This script contains two tables, first I need to query **sites_table** and then select the user which not exist in **roles_table**

**MY SQL SCRIPT LOOK LIKE THIS**

> **SELECT** s.sites_id, s.site_name, s.site_code
>
> **FROM** sites s
>
> **WHERE NOT EXISTS** (**SELECT** * **FROM** roles r **WHERE** s.sites_id = r.sites_id **AND** r.user_id = 3501)

**And I already converted to Laravel Query Builder.**

```
$st = DB::table("sites")
->select('sites_id','site_name','site_code')
->whereNotIn('sites_id',function($query) {
    $query->select('sites_id')
          ->from('roles')
          ->where('roles.user_id','1001');
          })          

->get();
```

I received Laravel Error like this.

> ErrorException
>
> Undefined variable: user
>
> http://127.0.0.1/wgms/public/users/3501/edit

Comment: we can not access this url as it is not in public domain, include as an image here, if it provides some more info

Comment: Most likely you forgot to properly pass $user variable into your closure. function ($query) use ($user) {...}

Comment: Issue is not with this query, there is variable `$user` you are using somewhere and that is not defined or not passed as closure as Leonid said.

Comment: @LeonidShumakov, you should provide it as an answer. That would be the only issue in this case.

Comment: >where('roles.user_id','1001'); is work but i want to use "$user->id" get method in my contoller

Answer (score 1):

The error says you're attempting to use variable $user that is not initialized in that scope.

If you're using closure in your query, most likely you just need to pass $user via use()

```
$st = DB::table("sites")
->select('sites_id','site_name','site_code')
->whereNotIn('sites_id',function($query) use ($user) {  // <---- $user will be passed into the function
    $query->select('sites_id')
          ->from('roles')
          ->where('roles.user_id',$user->id);
          })          

->get();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
> variables must be passed to the use language construct. From PHP 7.1,
> these variables must not include superglobals, $this, or variables
> with the same name as a parameter.

Comment: >where('roles.user_id','1001'); is work but i want to use "$user->id" get method in my contoller

Comment: @KazeiItsushi use `$user->id` in your where() after you add use($user) to definition of anonymous function. Just updated the sample.

Comment: wow, its worked now !. Laravel: Query Builder never teaches me about that. I love you, bro.
how do you know is there any reference syntax  by adding 'use ($user)'

Comment: This syntax is core of PHP. Just read about anonymous functions and practice a bit. It has nothing to do with Laravel or Database.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED CODE**

```
$sites_list  = DB::table("sites")
                        ->select('sites_id','site_name','site_code')
                        ->whereNotIn('sites_id',function($query) use ($user) { 
                            $query->select('sites_id')
                                  ->from('roles')
                                  ->where('roles.user_id', $user->id);
                                  })          

                        ->get();
```